# Continuous Integration Hosting for Open Source projects

Tags: java, continuous-integration, maven

I would like to integrate continuous integration with my projects.  My projects are currently up on github.

Any ideas what I can use to provide hosted continuous integration?  I know Cruise Control and Hudson are ideal candidates as well as Bamboo.  I just need to document it and have paper work for that.

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: Your question is essentially a duplicate of [Hosted Continuous Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380721/hosted-continuous-integration) that I suggest to check.

Comment: I guess I have to host it myself.  I already have a host, just don't want to tax it with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running Hudson locally which works, but is slightly less than desirable.  Since I am the only contributor it doesn't matter if the server is offline while I sleep.

Walter

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about hosting itself, but i am using amazon cloud for that, integrated with Atlassian Jira Studio

Answer (score 1):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) hands down the best Java based CI tool.  It nicely supports maven among other functions.  Its open source and supports plugin creation, so for instance you can run findbugs against your code and there is a plugin which it will visually display the findings.

Answer (score 0):

MikeCI is free for open source projects and they host on Amazon EC2. get in touch with them and they'll happily put you on their community edition, I know they've already got 7-8 open source projects and are wanting more (in exchange for feedback).

Great support too!
[Hosted Continuous Integration](http://www.mikeci.com)

Answer (score -1):

I use CC.Net, but the non .Net version works for Java and supports git : http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/ (or so the website says)

Answer (score -2):

If you're looking for a host just for your CI, you might want to look into Atlassian's [Jira Studio](http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/studio/). It's not free, and it has a significant overlap with what github gives you, but Atlassian make some *very* nice tools.